# Copy the jsonb array value to another field in jsonb object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transfer_test (
    "id" uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "status" text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    "txn_data" jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}',
);
```

I have to update the txn_data json

txn_data json:

```
{"id":"1","status":"325","status_result":"[{"id":1,"status":"2","message":"text"}]"}
```

So I need like this `txn_data` below the same message value with the new field where the status = `325` and status_result.status = 2

```
{"id":"1","status":"325","status_result":"[{"id":1,"status":"2","message":"text","err":"text"}]"}
```

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Is the structure of your json correct? Your status_result contains an array of elements, if there are several of them, which one will need to be changed?

Comment: where the status is 2. Sorry didn't mentioned that. Updating that now.

Comment: Note that Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: ok sure, thanks!  can you help me with the above.?